# why is this operation not permitted

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js on Windows 10 and I'm using Discord.js to make a discord bot, I need to save some data to a file after creating the file, and it works on my other Windows 10 machine, but when I run it on this one it says it's not permitted.

Why is this operation not permitted and how do i make it permitted, thanks!

[image]

Comment: That looks like a file permission issue.  It could also be Windows Defender or your current anti-virus program blocking write access for some reason so that particular directory or file.  I've seen some reports of MalwareBytes or the tamper protection in Windows causing this.  Or, it could just be a good ole plain file/directory permission issue.

Comment: EPERM is a permission error. That means that the user you used to run the node.js application (may or may not be your account depending on how you run it) will not be able to save the file in that location even if he used Notepad or Word

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text.

Answer (score 2):

i was using avast and had to create an exception in my anti virus, this fixed the issue, thanks all!